# How to inject into a Kotlin delegated property with Dagger 2?

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

I need to do (`@Named`) injection with dagger2 into a kotlin delegated property.

```
//works great!
@set:Inject var cat: Cat by Ref(ref)

//fails
@set:[Inject Named("dog")] var dog : Animal by Ref(ref)
```

So I tried

```
//fails, can't use `@field` with a delegated property
@field:[Inject Named("dog")] var dog : Animal by Ref(ref)

//fails, can't use `lateinit` with a delegated property
@field:[Inject Named("dog")] lateinit var dog : Animal by Ref(ref)
```

Comment: Any news on this? Did you found a way?

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot because such property doesn't have any field but instead, delegates get and set calls to delegate property object. And dagger knows nothing about this delegate, this is just 2 methods and an object.

I'm not sure about your case, but probably you can inject your delegate class instance Ref with required value, but I don't know what you want to do, how your delegate works and how do you use Dagger (what type of injection do you use)